# Lost Dashboard App

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a 3 yr. old MacBook Pro. Current OS X is 10.9.5.  I have lost Dashboard.  Geek Squad work over an hour to restore with no luck - any ideas?

Comment: By Geek Squad do you mean a person from geeksquad.com?  What happens if you open System Preferences and then choose Mission Control, and then look for "Show Dashboard as a space"?

Answer (score 1):

What's your output of command:

```
defaults read com.apple.dashboard
```

If it's disabled:

```
{
    "enabled-state" = 1;
}
```

If it's running as a space:

```
{
    "enabled-state" = 2;
}
```

If it's running as an overlay:

```
{
    "enabled-state" = 3;
}
```